# Transiting in London Heathrow

Tags: transit, lhr

I am traveling from Doha to Faro in Portugal via Heathrow.

I have a Schengen visa but no UK visa. I will need to transit from Terminal 4 ain Heathrow to Terminal 5. Will I be able to do this airside?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the general transit visa question. This one is asking specifically whether there's an airside connection between those two terminals at that particular airport. Knowing whether you need to enter the UK  is a _prerequisite_ to using the general answer for anything.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The other question's top answer links to Heathrow's transit guide. For John's benefit, [here it is](https://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections).